# How to decode sellingasset and buyingasset in python

Tags: stellar-core, xdr

I checked in public.offers from the core database. The sellingasset and buyingasset are base64 encoded.

Here's what I get from database and horizon api:

#### database

```
select buyingasset from offers where offerid=147863991;
```

> AAAAAVNMVAAAAAAAlA8rrxQ89pexgEv3wGm0Tu9RxisitWx4ONyNc5Xn7qg=

#### horizon api

```
"buying": {
          "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
          "asset_code": "SLT",
          "asset_issuer": "GCKA6K5PCQ6PNF5RQBF7PQDJWRHO6UOGFMRLK3DYHDOI244V47XKQ4GP"
        },
```

Question: how can I decode the XDR string to a readable string like the Horizon API is doing? Hopefully in Python code.

Answer (score 1):

get it!

xdrstr='AAAAAVNMVAAAAAAAlA8rrxQ89pexgEv3wGm0Tu9RxisitWx4ONyNc5Xn7qg='

tx_result = Xdr.StellarXDRUnpacker(base64.b64decode(xdrstr)).unpack_Asset()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [the answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/2948/1750) from Brian Mo(@brian-mo), here is the complete code, it works on 2.x version.

```
import base64
from stellar_sdk import Asset
from stellar_sdk.xdr import Xdr
xdr_str = 'AAAAAVNMVAAAAAAAlA8rrxQ89pexgEv3wGm0Tu9RxisitWx4ONyNc5Xn7qg='
xdr_obj = Xdr.StellarXDRUnpacker(base64.b64decode(xdr_str)).unpack_Asset()
asset = Asset.from_xdr_object(xdr_obj)
```

I know it looks a bit complicated, we have made some improvements and will release it some days later, here is a preview.

```
from stellar_sdk import Asset
xdr_str = 'AAAAAVNMVAAAAAAAlA8rrxQ89pexgEv3wGm0Tu9RxisitWx4ONyNc5Xn7qg='
asset = Asset.from_xdr(xdr_str)
```

You can find related improvements [here](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/pull/269) (not yet released).